# How to use variables in modal function's position option in SimpleModal 1.4.4

Tags: simplemodal

I am having an issue inserting variables into the modal functions position option. The following works:

```
        $.modal('<iframe id = "framedetails" src="' + src + '" height="' + vHeight + 'px;" width="' + vWidth + 'px;" style="border:0"></iframe>', {
        closeHTML:"<a href='#' class='modalCloseImg' alt='Close/Cancel' title='Close/Cancel'><a>", //add close button
        fixed: false, 
        position: ["75px","595.5px"],
        overlayClose:false
    });
```

How would I insert a variable for each of the position values?  I am unable to get the concatenation correct and have tried many variations.

For example, position: ["" + vTop + "","" + vLeft + ""] seems to insert the value for vTop but the vLeft variable is not being applied.  If I supply the actual value in this for vLeft, it works as expected.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out...pretty silly of me.  I just create a string array of the two variables (vTop and vLeft) and passed them in.

```
vArray = ["" + vTop + "","" + vLeft + ""];
```

...
    position: vArray